# How to extract Strings from Java files more elegantly?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I want to internationialize my app and because of that I have to extract all the hard-coded Strings to the `string.xml` file. Extracting the Strings in the `XML` layout files is easy, because Android Studio shows you a light bulb in every line with a hard-coded String through which you can easily extract your Strings.

How do you do that with Java files? Is there a way to extract the Strings of the Java files without having to manually type them out in the `string.xml` file?

Answer (score 1):

Click on hardcore text and press Alt+Enter and click on 'Extract String Resource':
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Press alt+enter and click Extract string resource
[image]

then fill resource name is id in string.xml
and resource value is value your string

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It works the same way as it does in your XML.

If you click on the string, you will see a small yellow bulb on your left, you can select extract resource there. If you're unable to locate the yellow bulb, you can press alt+enter to access the same.

Good luck.